# Python-change IDLE run to terminal

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm wondering, is it possible to actually run terminal/cmd from IDLE by pressing F5 like what we usualy do in IDLE? so when i'm pressing F5 the IDLE would run the terminal/cmd with my IDLE script in it instead the python shell?

Comment: I think you want the code written in IDLE to be executed in `cmd/terminal` when `F5` is pressed instead of running in `IDLE shell`. I think it's not possible to override the setting as IDLE offers no such setting.

Comment: You could try editing idlelib's code, add something along the lines of `subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe /k "cd {dirname} && python -i {filename}"'.format(dirname=dirname, filename=filename)` followed by `return 'break'` just before it tries to run its own shell in `idlelib/runscript.py`'s method `ScriptBinding._run_module_event` -- totally untested, may not work, may break idle, make a backup of that file first

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but I believe the answer is currently 'no'. I would like to add an option to run a file being edited with a standard console used for input and output instead of IDLE's Shell.  This would loose some features, such as being able to jump from a traceback to an editor window at the guilty code line, but would gain being able to test code as it would normally be used, after development is complete.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, so, the point is i want to change behavior of IDLE. usually, when we press F5 or [Run -> Run Module (F5)] the IDLE would load up the Python Shell and run my code in it. what i want is when i press F5, the IDLE would launch terminal and python shell in it and run my code in terminal, not in Python embed shell.